# Help with drawing in MetaPost

Tags: graphs, metapost

My drawing with MetaPost looks like:

[image]

I need to solve the following in the graph:

- Making the ends of the hyperbolas parallel with the two dashed lines
- Labelling the two focus points **F** like **F_1** and **F_2**.
- Making all the labels smaller

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[estonian]{babel} 
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\begin{document}

etex;
def genereeri(expr w, h, base) = 
begingroup 
write "\documentclass{article}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\usepackage{geometry}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\geometry{papersize={"& decimal(ceiling(w)) & "bp," &% 
decimal(ceiling(h)) & "bp}}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\geometry{margin={0bp,0bp}}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\geometry{noheadfoot,nomarginpar}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\begin{document}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\thispagestyle{empty}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\noindent\includegraphics{" & jobname & "." &% 
decimal(charcode) & "}" to base&".tex"; 
write "\end{document}" to base&".tex"; 
write EOF to base&".tex"; 
endgroup 
enddef;

beginfig(1);

drawarrow (-2cm,0)--(2cm,0);
drawarrow (0,-1.5cm)--(0,1.5cm);

label.bot("x", (1.5cm, 0));
label.lft("y", (0,1.5cm));

draw (-1.3cm,-1.3cm) -- (1.3cm,1.3cm) dashed evenly;
draw (-1.3cm,1.3cm) -- (1.3cm,-1.3cm) dashed evenly;

draw(1cm,-0.82cm) .. (0.4cm, 0) .. (1cm,0.82cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5pt;
draw(-1cm,-0.82cm) .. (-0.4cm, 0) .. (-1cm,0.82cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5pt;


draw(-0.1cm, -0.7cm) -- (0.75cm,0.9cm);

label.top("R", (0.275cm,0));
draw (0.275cm, 0) withpen pencircle scaled 2bp;

draw(1.4cm, -0.4cm) -- (0.25cm,0.7cm);

label.bot("F", (0.7cm,0cm));

label.rt("S", (0, -0.6cm));

label.bot("F", (-0.7cm,0cm));

label.bot("M", (0.8cm, 0.7cm));

label.bot("Joon.9.2.", (0, -1.5cm));
endfig;
end

numeric w,h; 
w := xpart urcorner bbox currentpicture -% 
xpart llcorner bbox currentpicture; 
h := ypart urcorner bbox currentpicture -% 
ypart llcorner bbox currentpicture; 
string base; 
base:=jobname&"_"&decimal(charcode); 
genereeri(w, h, base);

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please help us by showing us your current coding for this figure?

Comment: Right, forgot to add that, edited original post

Comment: Er… where is the attempted code for the hyperbola?

Comment: I'm very amateur to using metapost, so I just tried to use draw(1cm,-0.82cm) .. (0.4cm, 0) .. (1cm,0.82cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5pt;
draw(-1cm,-0.82cm) .. (-0.4cm, 0) .. (-1cm,0.82cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1.5pt; to make the hyperbola arcs, but it didn't work and I didn't find any help from the Internet

Comment: You need to specify the function for the hyperbola. I don't understand all the stuff with `base`, but `input latexmp` may be helpful if this isn't happening automatically. You can use LaTeX commands for the font selection. At least, I do. You can specify a `path` and then draw it later - not sure, but this is probably easier for drawing a more complex curve.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an attempt to draw the hyperbola `x^2 - y^2 = 1` with its focal points and asymptotes. The MetaPost code has been inserted in a LuaLaTeX program for convenience. It calls the Metafun format, mainly because it provides the hyperbolic functions, which I use to create the parametric curve giving the hyperbola.

To make you familiar with MetaPost and the way it should be used, I suggest a wonderful tutorial from André Heck, [Learning MetaPost by doing](https://staff.science.uva.nl/a.j.p.heck/Courses/mptut.pdf).

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
% Macro creating a parametric path
vardef parafcn(expr tmin, tmax, tstep)(text f_t)(text g_t) =
    save t; t := tmin;
    (f_t, g_t) forever: hide(t := t + tstep) exitunless t <= tmax; 
        .. (f_t, g_t) 
    endfor
    if t - tstep < tmax: hide(t := tmax) .. (f_t, g_t) fi
enddef;
% Parameters
u = cm; xmax = ymax = - xmin = -ymin = 4; 
tmax = -tmin = 2.2; tstep = .1;
beginfig(1);
    % Axes
    drawarrow (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0);   
    drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u);
    % Focus points
    pair F[]; F1 = (u*sqrt 2, 0) = -F2;
    for i = 1,2:
        drawdot F[i] withpen pencircle scaled 3bp; 
        label.bot("$F_{" & decimal i & "}$", F[i]);
    endfor;
    % Asymptotes
    drawoptions(dashed evenly);
    draw ((xmin, ymin) -- (xmax, ymax)) scaled u;
    draw ((xmin, ymax) -- (xmax, ymin)) scaled u;
    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled bp withcolor red);
    % (Clipped) Hyperbola
    path hyperb;
    hyperb = parafcn(tmin, tmax, tstep)(cosh t)(sinh t) scaled u;
    draw hyperb; draw hyperb reflectedabout (origin, (0, 1));
    clip currentpicture to 
        ((xmin, ymin) -- (xmax, ymin) -- (xmax, ymax) -- (xmin, ymax) -- cycle) 
            scaled u;
    % labels
    drawoptions();
    label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0)); label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax*u));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can extend the `-xmin = xmax = 4` type syntax to `pairs`, so here you could have put `F1 = -F2 = (u*sqrt 2,0)`.

Comment: @Thruston  Quite right. Done!